# How to wget images with different names?

Tags: wget

Is there a way to download files with different names from the website using **wget**.

For example: I want to download only these two files `test.jpg` and `test1.jpg`.

Comment: @Mayanak: You have write shell script for this need!

Comment: well, as far as I know, wget does not overwrite files, so `wget` in conjunction  with `rename(1)` should do the trick. `rename(1)` man page illustrate how to rename multiple files. Use `rename` after your done downloading.

Comment: I don't want to rename files. I want files with specific names from the site. I am currently running this command: wget -r -Q100m --mirror -nd -A "file_list.txt" jpg,jpeg -P /AlbumArt/test/ http://testsite.com

Comment: @Venkat I'm not familiar with shell script. Can you plz help me with it?

Comment: Sure! Please give your question in deeply . what is the request parameter and response stuff!

Comment: +1 for your good question!

Comment: Actually, this question is very confusing. What are the parameters of the two files you're trying to get? Are you trying to download all the files that have similar names, differing only by few characters? Are you trying to download all the files with unique names? Explain what you mean by "with different names" please.

Comment: By different names, I mean each file has unique name. For example: ManOfSteel.jpg, BatmanBegins.jpg. All are image files, basically cover art of albums. Please ask if there are further questions.